# electron/javascript: node.js calls not working from HTML script under a tabbed view

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I'm trying to trigger a function on page load. However, the page-load callback contains node.js calls, which seems to be broken.

The app uses `electron-tab` to implement a tabbed view.

### Code

The following HTML is the html page loaded from a tab: `tab1.html`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
        default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
        script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
        connect-src *">
        <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * self blob: data: gap:; style-src * self 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; object-src * 'self' blob: data: gap:; img-src * self 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; connect-src self * 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: gap:; frame-src * self blob: data: gap:;"> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Transport</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="OnLoadTransport();">

</body>
</html>
```

The JS

```js
const Path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs');
const glob = require('glob');


function OnLoadTransport() {
    alert('Here');
    var filePaths = ListDir(__dirname, ".json");
    alert(filePaths.length.toString());
    for(var f=0; f<filePaths.length; f++) {
        alert(filePaths[f]);
        LoadJSON(filePaths[f], function (response) {
            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(response);
            alert(response);
        });
    }
}

function ListDir(rootDir, ext) {
    if (!fs.existsSync(rootDir)) {
        alert("no dir: " + rootDir);
        return [];
    }
    var filePaths = fs.readdirSync(rootDir);
    filePaths = filePaths.filter(file => file.endsWith(ext));
    return filePaths;
};

function LoadJSON(path, callback) {
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', path, true); // Replace 'my_data' with the path to your file
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
            callback(xobj.responseText);
        }
    };
    xobj.send(null);   
}
```

The renderer

```js
const { remote, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
const TabGroup = require("electron-tabs");
const mainProc = remote.require('./main.js'); // plug in main process
const parser = new DOMParser();

let tabGroup = new TabGroup({
    newTab: {
        title: 'New Tab'
    }
});

tabGroup.addTab({
    title: 'Tab 1',
    src: './tab1.html',
    closable: false,
    active: true
});

tabGroup.addTab({
    title: "Tab 2",
    src: './tab2.html',
    closable: false,
    // visible: true,
    active: false  // tab button is foregrounded
});
```

`main.js`

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

let mainWindow = null;

app.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Hello from Electron');
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            webviewTag: true
        }
    });

    // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

    mainWindow.webContents.loadFile('./app/index.html');
    
    // mainWindow events, within app lifecycle
    mainWindow.webContents.on('did-fail-load', function() {
        console.log("Failed to load index.html");
    })
    
})
```

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
        default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
        script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
        connect-src *">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>MAM Hub</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- 2. Include the basic markup of the tabs view -->
    <div class="etabs-tabgroup">
        <div class="etabs-tabs"></div>
        <div class="etabs-buttons"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="etabs-views"></div>
    <!--
        3. Include initialization code, you can include another js file
        Or write directly the JS code here.
    -->
    <script>
        // You can also require other files to run in this process
        require('./renderer.js')
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

### Expectation

On page load, I expect to see a series of alerts:

1. `Here`
2. Path to a found JSON file
3. The content of the JSON file

### Observation

With this code, I can see the alert `Here`. But nothing more. The same code if run in an Electron `renderer.js` just works: I am able to see the alerts about the found JSON file and its content.

So my guess is that the `fs` call didn't work. However, there are no errors in the Chromium console.

How should I enable the node.js support in this case?

Comment: I ran this at my side and showing the json files well. Yes ran at renderer

Answer (score 0):

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
```

Maybe, I think you forgot to enable the `nodeIntegration` when you are creating the browser. To use the Node api at your `renderer.js`.
You should enable the `nodeIntegration` when you are creating new `BrowserWindow` at your `main.js`

Comment: My main.js has that `BrowserWindow()` call. I will add more details.

Comment: @kakyo With `nodeIntegration` flag?

Comment: If so, let me know how you create new BrowserWindow. Code snippet will be good

Comment: @kakyo Electron version is?

Comment: running Electron 1.7.6

Comment: Ok, then please upgrade your electron version

Comment: @kakyo I'd recommend you to use at least v7 version

Comment: I just installed a fresh version of Electron 7.1.12 and the problem is still there.

Comment: Actually i was wrong about the version in the beginning, 1.7.6 was the electron@get's version. Not Electron's version. I've been using 7.1.12 all this time.

Comment: So when you run the project the just showing this `alert('Here');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207735/discussion-between-tpikachu-and-kakyo).

Comment: Your gist project works.
Actually my test code without the tabbed view is almost the same as yours, which works.
The code in the question uses a tabbed view. This was updated after the initial post.
The node calls in renderer.js definitely works, but it does not work in the separate js "myscript.js" used by the tabbed html (not index.html).